# How to find the indexes of stimulated regions in 1D signal python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a 1D signal, where some part is at baseline and some at higher amplitude because of stimulus. I want to separate the stimulated segments.
Here is the image of attached signal
[image]
From the signal shown in image, i want to get the starting and end points for stimulated signal.
The signal can be generated using following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def generate_random_decimal_array(start, end, size):
    random_array = [random.uniform(start, end) for _ in range(size)]
    return random_array

# Simulation parameters
fs = 200  # Sampling frequency (Hz)
t_total = 5  # Total simulation time (seconds)

# Time vector
t = np.linspace(0, t_total, int(fs * t_total), endpoint=False)

# Signal parameters
baseline_amplitude = 0.05
stimulus_amplitude = 0.75
stimulus_duration = 1  # Duration of the stimulus (seconds)
recovery_duration = 1  # Duration of the recovery period after stimulus (seconds)
num_stimuli = 3  # Number of stimulated regions

# Initialize signal with baseline noise
signal = baseline_amplitude * np.random.randn(len(t))

# Randomly choose start times for each stimulated region
stimulus_periods = []
for _ in range(num_stimuli):
    start = random.randint(0, len(t) - int(fs * (stimulus_duration + recovery_duration)))
    end = start + int(fs * stimulus_duration)
    stimulus_periods.append((start, end))

# Apply stimulus and recovery for each period
for start, end in stimulus_periods:
    signal[start:end] = generate_random_decimal_array(0.3, 1.5, (end - start))
    recovery_start = end
    recovery_end = recovery_start + int(fs * recovery_duration)
    signal[recovery_start:recovery_end] = baseline_amplitude * np.random.randn(recovery_end - recovery_start)

# Plot the simulated signal
plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.title('Simulated Signal with Multiple Stimuli')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77888183/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Given that your injected noise is small, relative to signal magnitude,
it's unclear why you're having trouble separating the two.

Summary goal: Hidden `stimulus_periods` produced by the generator should be recovered by a signal analysis function.

There's lots of ways to go about this.

1. Report whether observed signal is above threshold of 0.25.
2. Cleanup signal with smoothed moving average window (low-pass filter), then threshold.
3. Cleanup signal with median window filter, then threshold (this won't introduce phase delay).
4. Use [SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) or other ML classifier technique. Start by training on labeled data, then do inference on some newly acquired observations.
5. Let [ruptures](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures) solve a Change Point Detection optimization problem for you -- it has beautiful math on the inside, is quick, and is robust to noise.